# Error in python requests 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 33: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-requests

I am getting this error when i try do do a requests.get:

```
url = "https://solucoes.receita.fazenda.gov.br/servicos/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Comprovante.asp"
headers = {
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR;q=0.8',
  'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Referer': 'https://solucoes.receita.fazenda.gov.br/servicos/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao.asp',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'
}
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 33: invalid continuation byte
```

How can I solve this issue, please?

I tried to remove the hedaers, but got the same error

Answer (score 1):

The website is issuing a redirect that has a header encoded in Latin-1.  This is unexpected by the requests module per this comment in the source:

```
        if resp.is_redirect:
            location = resp.headers["location"]
            # Currently the underlying http module on py3 decode headers
            # in latin1, but empirical evidence suggests that latin1 is very
            # rarely used with non-ASCII characters in HTTP headers.
            # It is more likely to get UTF8 header rather than latin1.
            # This causes incorrect handling of UTF8 encoded location headers.
            # To solve this, we re-encode the location in latin1.
            location = location.encode("latin1")
            return to_native_string(location, "utf8")
        return None
```

Its assumption is that the headers were encoded in UTF-8 but decoded Latin-1 in the underlying http module.  It looks like the headers *were* encoded in the "rarely used" Latin-1 so trying to "undo" the assumption by re-encoding in latin1 and decoding in the assumed UTF-8 encoding fails.

It is trying to redirect to:

[https://solucoes.receita.fazenda.gov.br/servicos/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Erro.asp?erro=Acesso%20não%20permitido](https://solucoes.receita.fazenda.gov.br/servicos/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Erro.asp?erro=Acesso%20n%C3%A3o%20permitido).

which appears to be an "Access not permitted" page.  The `ã` is the problematic character because it is being sent in the redirect encoded in Latin-1.  Solve the access problem and you'll probably solve your issue.

Comment: Looks like that block in `requests` could use a try/except block to handle the incorrect assumption.  I wonder if there's a way to detect it directly?